# Is there a way to store a reference to a specific component within the DOM?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

*The problem:*

I am currently working on a file tree, more specifically on a "Selected Folder" functionality. I'm doing this to have a specific target for creating new files and folders, other that the root folder. (I'm using Vue within Electron, but this is not really relevant to the question)

Selection happens on click. Due to the nature of file trees, I use recursive components (and this limits my 'easy' access to some components).

While achieving this on the back-end is trivial, my exact problem is that while marking the selected folder with, say a different background color or bold text (by binding an id or class that has some corresponding style on my stylesheet), I need to **unmark** the previously selected directory.

So, how do I gain access to an **indirect** (due to the recursive components) child component?

*What I've tried, and looked into:*

Now, I know that within JS you can't store pointers or references in variables (otherwise this would've been easily achieved by storing a reference to the previous DOM element).

I have some solutions up my sleeve, but they're really tedious and not very straightforward. Previously, I had to re-render (by re-reading) specific sub-directories, based on file system updates. I achieved this partial re-rendering by propagating child function calls from the root directory until I reached the directory that needed to be re-rendered. I had to do this since the FS watcher was created on the root component.

Similarly, I could do this with the un-marking task. When I select the new folder, I start by propagating child function calls until I reach the previously selected folder, and un-mark it by un-binding the style id. Having done this previously, I know it's not a pleasant method.

Since I can get the click event target, I wondered if I could somehow store any kind of reference to the previously 'selected' DOM element and just use that reference later when I need to 'deselect' it.

Here's what my folder component looks like. I tried giving self-explanatory names to the properties, but if there's any confusion, I'll answer any question.

```html
<folder-comp
          @openFile="openFile"
          v-for="folder of folders" 
          :key="`folder-${folder.shortFolderName}`"
          :folder-name="folder.shortFolderName"
          :ref="folder.shortFolderName"
          :full-folder-path="folder.fullFolderPath"
          :local-directory="recursiveScanDir"
          :indentation-level="indentationLevel + 1">
</folder-comp>
```

The propagation method I used was necessary previously since all I had was an event File System path, unrelated to my Vue structures, and so I needed to somehow translate traversing that path. Here, though, everything happens only within the Vue environment, so I thought there would be some sort of way to deal with this easily.

EDIT: Well, as it happened with me in the past, just writing about the problem itself on stackoverflow helped me reach a solution.

I have a Global Event Bus set up on my Vue project, so I can bind an event listener on the currently selected folder. Once another folder is clicked (thus selected), it emits an event in the Global Event Bus, triggering the previously selected folder. This is followed by the un-marking and the unbinding of the event listener.

This is only one solution though, so the question still stands. Is this a good solution? Are there any drawbacks to this approach? Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a global event bus, you can also use **state management such as Vuex**.  When you change folders, you simply dispatch an action.  This uses an `command pattern`, as opposed the the mentioned `listener pattern`.  You have the choice to make this action `asynchronous` or `synchronous` as well.

There are several ways to register your listeners/watchers, from within components, or outside of them.

Using this architecture will allow you to easily add undo/redo capabilities, and also be able to navigate back and forth through your history of `mutations`.

You also gain the integrated debug features provided by the Vue tools in your browser.

In fact, Vuex was built exactly for situations like this, when components need to communicate with each other but the parent/child prop/emit/inject mechanisms start to become tedious and and fall apart.

*There is a high probability that once you starting using Vuex, you will never look back.*

Comment: Thank you! I am actually already using Vuex, but only as a store. I'll look into how to fully take advantage of Vuex, as it seems that it can do much more than just handle some simple states.